# Combinatorics. Find the number of ways....... Need Explanation

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to arrange the numbers $ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2$ so that no arrangement ever contains three consecutive integers that are the same.

I have the solution but I don't understand it. Can you explain how its 7!/3!3! and how its 5!/3[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KbiT.png)

Comment: Let x=111.  The number of ways to arrange 0,0,0,x,2,2,2 is 7!/3!3!.  Let y= 222.  The numbers of ways to arrange 0,0,0,x,y is 5!/3.  And if z=0,0,0 the number of ways to arrange x,y,z is 3!.

Answer (score 1):

The count of ways to arrange $\{A,A,A,B,B,B, [CCC]\}$ where the block of three digits, $[CCC]$, is inseparable (a unit), is: $$\dfrac{7!}{3!~3!~\color{silver}{1!}}$$

This is the count of ways to select $3$ of $7$ places for the $A$, $3$ of the remaining $4$ places for the $B$, and all of the $C$ go into the last remaining place.   Because a unit is inseparable it occupies just one place.

We do similar to count the ways to arrange $\{A,A,A,[BBB], [CCC]\}$.   We count ways to select $3$ of $5$ places for the $A$, select $1$ of the remaining $2$ places to put all of the $B$, and all of the $C$ go in the last remaining place. $$\dfrac{5!}{3!~\color{silver}{1!}~\color{silver}{1!}}$$

Finally the count of ways to arrange $\{[AAA],[BBB],[CCC]\}$ is just $3!$.

All that remains is to select which digits are blocked or not, and put it all together using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.$$\frac{9!}{3!^3}-\binom{3}{1}\frac{7!}{3!^2}+\binom{3}{2}\frac{5!}{3!}-3!$$

Answer (score 1):

Let’s count the number of arrangements that contain $000$. Temporarily we’ll label the other six characters individually: $1_1,1_2,1_3,2_1,2_2,2_3$, and we’ll consider $000$ a single, indivisible characters. That gives us a total of $7$ characters to arrange, something that we can do in $7!$ different ways. However, the arrangements $0001_12_11_22_21_32_3$ and $0001_32_11_12_21_22_3$ aren’t supposed to be counted separately: when we remove the distinguishing subscripts from the ones and twos, both of them become simply $000121212$. Clearly we’ve overcounted, and the question is by how much.

Take any arrangement with $000$; I’ll use $000121212$ as an example. When the ones and twos were still labelled with subscripts, the ones could have been filled into their three positions in this arrangement in any permutation, i.e., in any of the $3!$ possible orders: $0001_121_221_32$, $0001_121_321_22$, $0001_221_121_32$, $0001_221_321_12$, $0001_321_121_22$, and $0001_321_221_12$. Similarly, the three labelled twos could have been filled into their three slots in any of the $3!$ possible permutations. Thus, this one arrangement corresponds to $3!\cdot3!$ permutations of the $7$ characters $000$ and $1_1,1_2,1_3,2_1,2_2,2_3$. We’ve counted each arrangement $3!\cdot3!$ times, so the actual number of *arrangements* is only $\frac{7!}{3!3!}$.

Exactly the same kind of reasoning is used in the next step. If we treat $000$ and $111$ as units and temporarily label the twos $2_1,2_2$, and $2_3$, we have five characters in all, and they can be arranged in $5!$ different ways. When we forget about the labels on the twos, we get an arrangement like $111200022$, for instance. But there are **six** different arrangements of the five characters $000,111,2_1,2_2$, and $2_3$ that all produce this same result, one for each permutation of the three twos. Thus, our figure of $5!$ counts the arrangement $111200022$ (and any other such arrangement) six times, once for each of the $3!$ ways in which the $3$ labelled two could be inserted into that arrangement. We’ve overcounted by a factor of $3!$, so the correct count is $\frac{5!}{3!}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $\frac {7!}{3!3!}$ comes from considering the three numbers $iii$ as a unit.  You now have seven items, the group $iii$ and the other six numbers.  You can put them in order in this many ways, because you have two groups of three identical items.  $\frac {5!}{3!} comes about from grouping two sets of numbers, so there are five items, the two groups and the three other numbers, of which one set of three is identical.